# I am unable to log into Trello on a different machine or via a different browser

Tags: trello

Simple and gloriously weird.

I registered and that login, in IE9, has persisted nicely - to go trello.com and there I am.

But if I go to another machine and try to log in I can't (username or password not valid) same thing in a different browser. Doesn't matter if I use my email or my username.

Obvious question is whether I've remembered the password correctly? So I follow the forgotten password link and I get "member not recognised". This is true using both my email address and my username (which I can cut/paste from the instance where I am logged in).

One assumes that this is a bug - but nowhere else to ping support.

Answer (score 2):

From their [help page](https://trello.com/help):

> If you are having problems with your account or experiencing crashes, please email Fog Creek at support@trello.com. Please include detailed information regarding the nature of the problem including the browser and operating system. We respond to all email within one business day.

There doesn't appear to be a direct link to that page though. I had to go via the about page.

Comment: I chased around for ages failing to find any support contact details! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue: I could only log in on the browser where I had initially created my Trello account (using Google as OpenID provider).

I'm using Chrome and it turned out that it was blocking 3rd party cookies, which apparently are required for Trello session cookies. Allowing 3rd party cookies for trello.com fixed it for me. I recommend you check your cookie settings.